# formula to calculate the triangle side width

Tags: javascript, math

Math question i have google around for a while, there r quite few calculation out there but doesn't supply you with the formula.

for example this one: http://www.calculator.net/triangle-calculator.html?vc=30&vx=2&vy=2&va=&vz=&vb=&angleunits=d&x=94&y=27

[image]

**Question:**

What's the formula in **javascript** to calculate out the that `1.035`, say if you know two side width (side 1 and side 3) `2` and angle is `30` degrees (opposite angle).

Comment: The same as in regular math, [SAS (Side Angle Side) Law of Cosines / Sines formula(s)](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/trig-solving-sas-triangles.html)

Comment: @PatrickEvans please leave in the answer i will mark as correct

Comment: @pep you can delete your silly comment above and i will do mine. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula of solving SAS triangle is 
       **a^2 = b^2 + c^2 − 2bc cosA**

```
    function solveSide(a, b, C) {
    C = degToRad(C);
    if (C > 0.001)
        return Math.sqrt(a * a + b * b - 2 * a * b * Math.cos(C));
    else  
        return Math.sqrt((a - b) * (a - b) + a * b * C * C * (1 - C * C / 12));
   }

   function degToRad(x) {
       return x / 180 * Math.PI;
   }
   calculate(2,2,30);
```

output: **1.0352761804100827**

Comment: Check the updated one. In my first one I did not convert degree to radians. So output may vary